# Why is a return type of () expected even though it is set to bool?

Tags: rust

In a function that is declared to return `bool`:

```
pub fn is_palindrome(num: u64) -> bool {
    let mut digits = Vec::new();
    let mut temp = num;
    loop {
        digits.push(temp % 10);
        temp /= 10;
        if temp == 0 {
            break;
        }
    }
    for i in 0..digits.len() / 2 {
        if digits[i] != digits[digits.len() - i] {
            false // HERE I GET THE ERROR !!!!!!!
        }
    }
    true
}
```

I get an error while compiling:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:13:13
   |
13 |             false
   |             ^^^^^ expected (), found bool
   |
   = note: expected type `()`
              found type `bool`
```

Why is this happening, and how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because you have an early return and not placing the `return` keyword before it, as shown below:

```
if digits[i] != digits[digits.len() - i] {
    return false
}
```

This is because all functions evaluate the last line as a return value. If you want to return before going through the last line, you should add the `return` keyword.

An additional input here is to refactor your code so that it only returns once:

```
pub fn is_palindrome(num: u64) -> bool {
    let mut digits = Vec::new();
    let mut temp = num;
    let mut retval = true;
    loop {
        digits.push(temp % 10);
        temp /= 10;
        if temp == 0 {
            break;
        }
    }
    for i in 0..digits.len() / 2 {
        if digits[i] != digits[digits.len() - i] {
            retval = false; // you might want to put a break here so that it exits the loop after finding the first issue
        }
    }
    retval
}
```